# would a merge statement work here?

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a hard time wrapping my thoughts on how to approach this: I have some legacy data migrated into SQL 2008 SP1 64 BIT. The legacy schema used a surrogate key for event ID, e.g. event1, event2,enventn and for unknow reasons, include an additional column "valid_event_id", e.g. the row with "event_ID='1'" would have ""valid_event_ID='25'". We have no plans to determine the source or reason of the valid event field, and assume its there for a reason.

Fast forward....we've migrated this table into a new schema using GUID as the event_ID unique identifier, and cross-walked the original event_id's into new GUID's with no problem.

Now I'm struggling with a merge statement...don't even know where to start, on how to cross-walk the old valid_event_id's to their corresponding new GUID's.

E.g

First Row Old table

```
    [OLD_EVENT_ID]'event1',
    [OLD_VALID_EVENT_ID]'event25'
```

25th row old table:

```
[OLD_EVENT_ID]'event25',
[OLD_VALID_EVENT_ID]'NULL'
```

First row new table: 
`[new_EVENT_ID]'E42DDB84-1666-E111-A1B2-0023AE8F2836'` (matches event1)

25th row new table: 
`[new_EVENT_ID]'E482CEE5-1E66-E111-A1B2-0023AE8F2836'` (matches event25)

The row with [event_ID]'EE482CEE5-1E66-E111-A1B2-0023AE8F2836' would also calculate [valid_event_ID]'E482CEE5-1E66-E111-A1B2-0023AE8F2836'

I hope this makes sense!

Here is a snippet of the table in question, with a few records to exemplify:

The row with `8C436BD5-8665-E111-A1B2-0023AE8F2836` has an [ATBI_valid_event_id] of `Event_009056`. The goal is to populate the [Valid_Event_ID] column of same the row with the GUID `A9A67562-1E66-E111-A1B2-0023AE8F2836`, the GUID that corresponds to the other row with `event_009056`. Note that row `A9A67562-1E66-E111-A1B2-0023AE8F2836` does not have a [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID], and thus is not subject to this operation, other than providing the new GUID to back-track valid_event_id's

```
CREATE TABLE #events(
    [Event_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [Valid_Event_ID] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [ATBI_EVENT_ID] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT #events([Event_ID], [Valid_Event_ID], [ATBI_EVENT_ID], [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID]) VALUES (N'8c436bd5-8665-e111-a1b2-0023ae8f2836', NULL, N'Event_009055', N'Event_009056')
INSERT #events([Event_ID], [Valid_Event_ID], [ATBI_EVENT_ID], [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID]) VALUES (N'4f476bd5-8665-e111-a1b2-0023ae8f2836', NULL, N'Event_009929', N'Event_009928')
INSERT #events([Event_ID], [Valid_Event_ID], [ATBI_EVENT_ID], [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID]) VALUES (N'd8486bd5-8665-e111-a1b2-0023ae8f2836', NULL, N'Event_039507', N'Event_039508')
INSERT #events([Event_ID], [Valid_Event_ID], [ATBI_EVENT_ID], [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID]) VALUES (N'52fd817c-8d65-e111-a1b2-0023ae8f2836', NULL, N'Event_005734', N'Event_005735')
INSERT #events([Event_ID], [Valid_Event_ID], [ATBI_EVENT_ID], [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID]) VALUES (N'05a791f5-1566-e111-a1b2-0023ae8f2836', NULL, N'Event_005735 ', NULL)
INSERT #events([Event_ID], [Valid_Event_ID], [ATBI_EVENT_ID], [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID]) VALUES (N'7dea8f4a-1e66-e111-a1b2-0023ae8f2836', NULL, N'Event_009928 ', NULL)
INSERT #events([Event_ID], [Valid_Event_ID], [ATBI_EVENT_ID], [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID]) VALUES (N'a9a67562-1e66-e111-a1b2-0023ae8f2836', NULL, N'Event_009056 ', NULL)
INSERT #events([Event_ID], [Valid_Event_ID], [ATBI_EVENT_ID], [ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID]) VALUES (N'd93afbc1-1e66-e111-a1b2-0023ae8f2836', NULL, N'Event_039508 ', NULL)
```

Comment: What is "cross-walking"? Is this a new type of sport?

Comment: I'm also not sure what "25th row" means. How do you define the 25th row in a table? I'm not trying to be facetious but could you show us the 25 rows (or 10, or whatever would illustrate the point better)? I suspect that if all you're doing is updating the new table based on the old table, you don't need `MERGE` - we just need to understand before/after better based on old/new tables.

Comment: What I'm getting at, is are there 23 values in between, with things like 'event2', 'event3', 'event4', ..., 'event24'... and these all correlate to different GUIDs in the new table? And you're trying to make them all the same across all 25 events? Sample data on both sides and before/after desired by the update would be helpful.

Comment: So after the update, should the last 4 rows in your sample stay the same, and the first row, for example, be updated to have a GUID of 'A9A...' instead of '8C4...'?

Comment: "We have no plans to determine the source or reason of the valid event field, and assume its there for a reason"  If you don't know if you need it or what it means exactly how can you assure you have correctly converted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE e SET Valid_Event_ID = e2.Event_ID
  FROM #events AS e
  INNER JOIN #events AS e2 
ON e.ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID = e2.ATBI_EVENT_ID
WHERE e.ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID IS NOT NULL;

SELECT * FROM #events;
```

Results:

```
Event_ID  Valid_Event_ID  ATBI_EVENT_ID  ATBI_VALID_EVENT_ID
8C43....  A9A6....        Event_009055   Event_009056
4F47....  7DEA....        Event_009929   Event_009928
D848....  D93A....        Event_039507   Event_039508
52FD....  05A7....        Event_005734   Event_005735
05A7....  NULL            Event_005735   NULL
7DEA....  NULL            Event_009928   NULL
A9A6....  NULL            Event_009056   NULL
D93A....  NULL            Event_039508   NULL
```

Comment: wow. very simple an elegant. of course it worked very quickly. I guess I made the logic more complex than it needed to be. THanks!.